# create json object in specific format

Tags: php, javascript

i want to write a script by which i can generate the json like in below format.

```
[
        [ "20 aug 2013",                                      
            [
                {lbl1: "Titanium Card",lbl2: "$2000",lbl3: "$400",img1234:"checkboxwhite.png"}, 
                {lbl1: "Gold Card",lbl2: "$1000",lbl3: "$500",img1234:"checkboxwhite.png"}, 
                {lbl1: "Silver Card",lbl2: "$800",lbl3: "$600",img1234:"checkboxwhite.png"}
            ]
        ],

        [ "22 aug 2013",                                               
            [
                {lbl1:"Savings 1", lbl2: "$400",lbl3:"N/A",img1234:"checkboxwhite.png"},
                {lbl1: "Savings 2", lbl2: "$400",lbl3: "N/A",img1234:"checkboxwhite.png"}

            ]
        ],
        [ "24 aug 2012",
            [                                                     
                {lbl1: "Checking 1",lbl2: "N/A",lbl3: "$400",img1234:"checkboxwhite.png"},
                {lbl1: "Checking 2",lbl2: "N/A",lbl3: "$400",img1234:"checkboxwhite.png"}
            ]
        ]     
    ];
```

Json object:

```
var jsonObj= {"20th Aug 2013":[{"agenda":"Eventbuilder program session for next events","endtime":"20th Aug 2013 16:00 pm","starttime":"20th Aug 2013 09:00 am","status":"1","location":"Sardar Patel Stadium, Ahmedabad, Gujarat","speaker":"Salim Kg","parent":"0","type":"Entertainment","lang":"72.5644771","id":"1","title":"Eventbuilder program session","isAttend":0,"app_id":"2","speaker_id":"1","lat":"23.0419169","floor_plan":"floorplan_2.png","handoutfile":"test1.pdf"}],"18th Aug 2013":[{"agenda":"entertainment weekly events","endtime":"18th Aug 2013 16:00 pm","starttime":"18th Aug 2013 09:00 am","status":"1","location":"GMDC Ground Counter1,Ahmedabad","speaker":"Salim Kg","parent":"0","type":"Entertainment","lang":"72.5669487","id":"2","title":"Eventbuilder Team meeting ","isAttend":1,"app_id":"2","speaker_id":"1","lat":"23.0400935","floor_plan":"floorplan_3.png","handoutfile":""}],"17th Aug 2013":[{"agenda":"entertainment weekly events","endtime":"17th Aug 2013 16:00 pm","starttime":"17th Aug 2013 09:00 am","status":"1","location":"GMDC Ground Counter2,Ahmedabad","speaker":"Salim Kg","parent":"0","type":"Entertainment","lang":"72.5644771","id":"3","title":"8th International Workshop on Commercial Law","isAttend":1,"app_id":"2","speaker_id":"1","lat":"23.0419169","floor_plan":"","handoutfile":"sc3.pdf"}],"16th Aug 2013":[{"agenda":"entertainment weekly events","endtime":"16th Aug 2013 16:00 pm","starttime":"16th Aug 2013 09:00 am","status":"1","location":"Sardar Patel Stadium, Ahmedabad, Gujarat","speaker":"Salim Kg","parent":"0","type":"Entertainment","lang":"72.5644771","id":"4","title":"Team building ","isAttend":0,"app_id":"2","speaker_id":"1","lat":"23.0419169","floor_plan":"","handoutfile":"sc4.pdf"}],"19th Aug 2013":[{"agenda":"entertainment weekly events","endtime":"19th Aug 2013 16:00 pm","starttime":"19th Aug 2013 09:00 am","status":"1","location":"GMDC Ground Counter1,Ahmedabad","speaker":"Salim Kg","parent":"0","type":"Entertainment","lang":"72.5669487","id":"5","title":"Ceritification course","isAttend":1,"app_id":"2","speaker_id":"1","lat":"23.0400935","floor_plan":"","handoutfile":""}],"21st Aug 2013":[{"agenda":"entertainment weekly events","endtime":"21st Aug 2013 16:00 pm","starttime":"21st Aug 2013 09:00 am","status":"1","location":"GMDC Ground Counter2,Ahmedabad","speaker":"chirag ch","parent":"0","type":"Entertainment","lang":"72.5644771","id":"6","title":"Networking Breakfast","isAttend":0,"app_id":"2","speaker_id":"2","lat":"23.0419169","floor_plan":"","handoutfile":""}]};
```

My code but not success

```
var keyArr =[];
    for (var key in jsonObj) {
        keyArr.push(key);

    }
    var i =0;
    for(i=0;i<keyArr.length; i++){
        //console.log(jsonObj[keyArr[i]]);
        //console.log("main obj=="+jsonObj[keyArr[0]]);
        keyArr.i =[];
        for(x in jsonObj[keyArr[i]]){
            keyArr.i.push({
                lbl1:jsonObj[keyArr[i]][x]['title'],
                lbl2:jsonObj[keyArr[i]][x]['agenda'],
                template:"hboxEventSection"
            });
        }

    }
    console.log(keyArr);
```

Please help

thanks in advance.

Comment: But that's not JSON...

Comment: yes its not json  but i need the output in above format.

Comment: Please show what the input data looks like.

Comment: Show us what you tried to achieve that output.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in means to do this. PHP's JSON functions are designed to compact the data as much as possible for transfer or storage. It is not meant to be a human-readable format, therefore unnecessary white space is eliminated.

You will have to write your own code to loop over your array and generate the format from your example manually.